# How can i extract value of each fields of each table of multiple tables of html file using perl

Tags: html, perl

I want to convert html output of file into IVIL format, for that i want to retreive value of each field of multiple table present on html file. How should i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [HTML::TableExtract](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract). The module can easily extract information from HTML tables.

Comment: Yes, i know this module can be used to retrive table but i want to retrive individuals field value also. Can you give more detail on how to retreive field value?

Comment: @yogeshYadav: Have you read the module's documentation I linked to? What parts do you have problems understanding?